# Zoom in close the infoWindow

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Any experts can help me in google map :

I created a map with marker and `infoBubble` or `infoWindow`. The default view is lat,long,zoom.
When I click the marker, the `infoBubble` open and the map zoom to specific closer view number, say it 4. What I need is, when I press x to close the `infoBubble`, then the map back to default setting.

Thank your kind assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Define a global variable and set it when infowindow is opening, say it lastZoom:

`lastZoom = map.getZoom();`

On every before opening infowindow, set it your specific number. e.g.:

```
...
lastZoom = 4;
infowindow.open(...);
...
```

To return to the last zoom, you need a closeclick event for infowindow:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function() {
   map.setZoom(lastZoom);
});
```